# How to track points plotted in an ECDF back to an original data frame in R?

Tags: r, ecdf, envstats

So I started with 5 data frames corresponding to different categories. Let's call them `d1,d2,d3,d4,d5` defined with the code:

```
d1<-data.frame(runif(1000,0,10000))
d2<-data.frame(runif(1000,0,10000)) 
d3<-data.frame(runif(1000,0,10000)) 
d4<-data.frame(runif(1000,0,10000)) 
d5<-data.frame(runif(1000,0,10000))
```

I combined these five data frames into one huge data frame:

`all_data<-data.frame(d1, d2, d3, d4, d5)`

I then converted this big data frame into a vector to use with `ecdfPlot` with the code:

`all_data_v<-as.vector(t(all_data))`

I then created an ecdf plot on a log-log scale:

`ecdfPlot(all_data_v,log="yx",xlim=c(0.01,1000),ylim=c(0.001,1))`

I am looking at the points less than or equal to 1, specifically trying to determine the percentage of points present from each data frame in that range. My question is: Is there any way I can separate the points less than or equal to 1 and track them back to their original data frame? In other words, find the points less than or equal to 1 and determine whether they came from `d1, d2, d3, d4 or d5`?

I have tried to add the `plot.it=FALSE` argument to `ecdfPlot` which returns the points that it plots, but it doesn't tell me where the points come from.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `data.frame(data.frame(runif(2)),data.frame(runif2))` is ... such a horrible way to make sample data (well, *any* data). How about `set.seed(2); as.data.frame(matrix(runif(1000*5), nc=5))`?

Comment: Where is `ecdfPlot` defined?

Comment: EnvStats package

Comment: So are you trying to filter out values <= 1 before making the ecdf plot? It's unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: No, I'm trying to filter out the x=1 values after making the ecdf plot and finding out where they originally came from